# Does anyone recognize the function from this picture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, graphing-functions, special-functions

I was playing with the exterior algebra, and stumbled on this interesting function from $\Bbb N^2 \to \Bbb N$, which I'll call $f(x,y)$. This is plotted from $1 \leq x,y \leq 100$:

[image: 2D function]

In this picture, yellow values are higher, blue values are lower. So you can see the function is at its lowest when $x:y$ is closest to a simple ratio.

For all $x$, we have $f(x,x) = 2$. However, for sufficiently large $x$, we also have $f(x,x+1) = 3$, $f(x,x+2)=4$, etc, so this function is also in some sense measuring the *distance* to the nearest low-slope line.

In comparison, here's the gcd(x,y) function:

[image: gcd]

So you can see that while both functions feature prominent rational slopes, that the first one seems to be "smoothed" relative to the GCD, and also reaches *minima* at rational slopes rather than *maxima*.

Is there some simple function that this resembles?

Here is a CSV, if anyone wants to play with it, but due to the way I calculated this function, there may be some sporadic errors (though should be good for $x,y < 50$ or so: https://pastebin.com/raw/vEWAdBVM

---

Just to say how I got this function:

So for each $x,y$ pair, I generated the vector $(x,y,1)$. Then, I wanted to find the "shortest" integer bivector that is the wedge product of $(x,y,1) \wedge v$ for some $v$ with integer coordinates. This is a plot of the norm of the resulting shortest bivector for each $(x,y)$.

I was using the $\ell_1$ norm to measure shortest for the thing I'm doing, but you get the same basic plot with the $\ell_2$ norm, as well as any $\ell_p$ norm.

For each $(x,y)$ pair above, I ran a Monte Carlo search testing 10000 randomly generated bivectors and took the best one; after a few tries everything converged to the plot above.

If you start with $(x,y,0)$ instead, you seem to get the basic GCD function instead, but $(x,y,1)$ gives the "smooth nega-GCD" pattern above.

I was surprised to find something so simple and beautiful from such a strange starting point!

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that $f(n,n^2-n)=n$ and $f(n,k)=n+1$ for all $k>n^2-n$.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to calculate a bivector/wedge product, for people like me for whom it's not clear?

Comment: @GregMartin the wedge product is basically an antisymmetric tensor product - there are all kinds of abstract characterizations of the exterior algebra, but probably the simplest is just to treat the wedge product of two vectors $a \wedge b$ as $a\otimes b - b \otimes a$. You can also treat it as the algebra given by the relation $a \wedge b = -b \wedge a$, which (if you use this identity on the basis elements and extend via linearity) is equivalent and also lets you get trivectors and general multivectors. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

Comment: @GregMartin: It should be fine to replace "wedge product" by "cross product" here, as I'm fairly sure the OP is identifying $\wedge^2 V$ with $V$ via the Hodge star (or endowing $\wedge^2 V$ with a norm that would correspond to the usual norm on $V$ under this identification). So the OP is looking at the norm of the shortest nonzero vector in the $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ generated by $\left(0,1,-y\right)$, $\left(-1,0,x\right)$ and $\left(y,-x,0\right)$. For comparison, the norm of the shortest nonzero vector in the $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated ...

Comment: ... by $\left(0,y\right)$ and $\left(x,0\right)$ is $\gcd\left(x,y\right)$, by Bezout's theorem.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: Is the result really independent on the choice of norm, or only to some extent?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for the concrete translation of this wedge product! Your example in $\Bbb Z^2$ isn't quite right, since we just get a rectangular lattice with those two vectors ... perhaps the gcd comes from just a 1-dimensional lattice?

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes -- my 2-dimensional example should be 1-dimensional.

Comment: The curve has the same basic features regardless of the norm, with only minor differences - I'll try to get some pictures later

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, it's not an exact match, but it reminds me a lot of [this graph](https://old.reddit.com/r/mathpics/comments/bbd7yd/runtimes_for_euclids_gcd_algorithm/) of the number of iterations required for Euclid's GCD algorithm.

Comment: For real-numbered iteration counts see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Average